# How can i communicate between my app and a device using BLE?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, gatt

I am trying to establish and test communication between my iOS app and an external device with a BLE module (TI's CC2541). I have gone through a lot of documentation on how to go about doing this and i have understood bits and pieces. My understanding at the present moment (correct me if i'm wrong or if theres a better way of doing this) is that i have to create a GATT Server custom to the services that my app provides and i have to put in the values from the server into the app and controller according to the server profile.

The following questions are plaguing my progress:

1. How do I go about creating this profile? (I'm assuming I will have to isolate all the services and characteristics that my app and device will provide)
2. What is the proper process from scratch when going about establishing connection and communication using a custom profile?
3. Is there a particular set format that i must conform to to represent my data in frames?

Any response is much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor) tutorial. It will show you how to construct an iOS app that communicates with a BLE device. Modifying it to work with your particular device should be easy.

Comment: Thanks but I've already looked at this before, this example uses a gatt profile which is already defined for the service that it provides. I wanted more in terms of custom profiles and servers.

Comment: On BLE server side usually the BLE SOC vendors provide some templates for developing the custom profile check on  SDK provided for BLE module (TI's CC2541) for templates where you can design your custom profiles .

Comment: Thanks. Let me spend some more time on this and i'll get back.